# Layer not change opacity in animation

Tags: objective-c, calayer, cabasicanimation

I have method with animation:

```
-(void)AnimateRemovedScoreBall:(Field*)ballToRemove
{
    @try
    {
        CABasicAnimation *flash = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        flash.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
        flash.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
        flash.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1;
        flash.duration = 1.0;        // 1 second
        flash.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        flash.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        flash.additive = NO;
        [ballToRemove.ballLayer addAnimation:flash forKey:@"flashAnimation"];
    }
    @catch(NSException* ex)
    {
        NSLog(@"Bug captured in method AnimateRemovedScoreBall: %@ %@",ex, [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
    }
}
```

Ball layer is create like that :

```
-(CALayer*)CreateBallLayer:(CGColorRef)color coordinates:(CGRect)coordinates
{
    CALayer *ballLayer = [CALayer layer];
    @try
    {
        ballLayer.frame = coordinates;
        ballLayer.backgroundColor = color;
        ballLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [ballLayer setCornerRadius:25/2];
    }
    @catch(NSException* ex)
    {
        NSLog(@"Bug captured in method CreateBallLayer: %@ %@",ex, [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
    }
    return ballLayer;
}
```

Caller of animation method

```
-(void)RemoveScoreBalls:(NSArray*)scorePoints
{
    @try
    {
        for (NSValue* pointValue in scorePoints) {
            CGPoint point = [pointValue CGPointValue];
            Field* field = [self FindFieldWithPoint:point];
            [self AnimateRemovedScoreBall:field];
            NSInteger fieldIndex = [self.fieldsArray indexOfObject:field];
            field.ballColor = nil;
            field.ballLayer.backgroundColor = nil;
            field.ballLayer = nil;
            [self.fieldsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:fieldIndex withObject:field];
        }
    }
    @catch(NSException* ex)
    {
        NSLog(@"Bug captured in method RemoveScoreBalls: %@ %@",ex, [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
    }
}
```

This animation should make layer not visible, but it not happend :/ What I do wrong ?

Comment: Nothing's jumping out at me about the creation of the ball or the AnimateRemoveScoreBall method.  Maybe the issue is in how you call AnimateRemoveScoreBall.  Can you post the code that calls that method?

Comment: Are you sure "FindFieldWithPoint:" method returns a valid field?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the beginTime is not correct. can you remove the beginTime's configuration, and have a try, i am not sure.